# Content Editor WP or Script Editor WP won't show Content when Saving List as Template

Tags: list, web-part, splistitem, list-template, cewp

I created a List Template with a Content Editor Web Part in it and I made sure to click the "Include Content" button when I created the template but my list template does not have the Content Editor WebPart when I go to use it. Does anyone know how I can create a List Template with a Content Editor WP in it?

Comment: How did you added the CEWP to list means as list item? can you please provide a screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening SP Designer 2013, I went to the lists and libraries, selected my list and edited the "AllItems.aspx" File. In this file, I put in my HTML that I wanted to show up in the list template.

From here, I saved the .aspx file and went to my site. Then, I went to the list, hit the site actions button and clicked on "Edit this Page". I edited the List Properties and made it "hidden".

Finally, I went to my site content and clicked on the list settings. From here I saved the list as a template and my HTML shows up whenever I add the list anywhere on any site. This was the only way I managed to get HTML inside of a list template working flawlessly.